# Makefiles, building source from another folder with obj files into subfolder of current?

Tags: makefile

### Background

I've been stuck on this one for a while now so really hoping someone can help! I have an array of folders of C/C++ source that are common code to several projects, and some more folders (by the side of the others) that contain projects themselves.

When I build a project, I want to be able to include a sources.mk from an external folder, and have the objects for those included sources go into a subfolder of the project directory so as not to clutter the common folder up with project-specific objects (each project can have different flags, optimisations etc.)

As an example, here's a folder structure:

```
source/common.mk
source/common/stuff/aaa.c
source/common/stuff/sources.mk
source/projects/thing/main.c
source/projects/thing/Makefile
```

The Makefile in projects/thing will include ../../common/stuff/sources.mk to get a list of the sources in that folder (to be appended to the list of sources already in Makefile), and will include ../../common.mk to get rules for making .o from .c.

Sources in sources.mk are prepended with the relative path between Makefile and sources.mk as follows:

```
THIS_TOP := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
SOURCES_C += $(THIS_TOP)/aaa.c
```

I want all objects to go into (dir I'm building in)/objdir/, preferably with subfolders based on the path from source so e.g.:

```
cd projects/thing; make
```

should create:

```
projects/thing/objdir/main.o
projects/thing/objdir/common/stuff/aaa.o
```

So, I make a list of object files and strip the ../ out of the relative path as follows:

```
__OBJECTS=$(SOURCES_C:.c=.o) $(SOURCES_CPP:.cpp=.o)
_OBJECTS = $(subst ../,,$(__OBJECTS))
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJECTS))
```

### So far so good, right? But...

This lot makes a list of exactly how I want my objects making, no problem there. I can make objdir and its subfolders based on the contents of the list, and I can provide this list as a dependency to the final executable. If the objects were actually there I'd be fine!

The problem I have is that I can't seem to come up with a rule (to go in common.mk) to make this local .o from a remote .c! I've tried a second expansion to try to make a rule that searches in the list of .c files for the one that corresponds to the .o that is required, but can't make that work due to the lack of multiple wildcards in filter...

```
.SECOND_EXPANSION:
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $$(filter %$$(addsuffix .c,$$(subst .o,,$$(notdir $$@))),$$(SOURCES_C))
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(WARNINGS) $(DEPGENFLAGS)
```

I'm really tearing my hair out on this one... has anyone managed something similar? If all else fails I'll just build them as static libraries (already have libraries building in subdir of project folder like I want) but since that creates extra makefiles to maintain I'd really like to avoid it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

### Thanks,

Olly

Answer (score 0):

V'been scratching my head on your issue, and decided in the end that it does not seem possible to do what you want with one single `.o:.c` pattern rule. You have to rely on one pattern rule per *library* directory.

My suggestion would be to define a pattern rule in each `sources.mk` file that would use two variables that would be provided by the *main* `Makefile`:

```
TOPDIR = ../..
OBJDIR = objdir
```

With the pattern rule defined into the `sources.mk` file as follows:

```
$(OBJDIR)/$(THIS_TOP)/*.o: $(TOPDIR)/$(THIS_TOP)/*.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(WARNINGS) $(DEPGENFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... I had a go at this, but for some reason (most likely my own mistakes but still) couldn't get *any* pattern to be used for turning e.g. `../../common/stuff/aaa/c` into `objdir/common/stuff/aaa.o` - I tried your format and as many variations as I could think of! For the time being I'm compiling such folders into static libraries and then linking them in, will revisit this when I have thought about it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`vpath`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search)?

I would try writing something like

```
vpath %.c <path/to/source/common/relative/to/your/objdir/common>
```

I'm not sure that this will work because %-pattern may be a file-with-its-path which comes from complex .o:.c rule you use.

Another possible approach is to provide two distinct implicit rules for making `$(OBJDIR)/common/%.o` and `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` with the same recipe:

```
COMPILE_C = $(CC) -o $@ $< $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(WARNINGS) $(DEPGENFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/common/%.o : <relative/path/to/source/common>/%.c
    $(COMPILE_C)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : ../%.c
    $(COMPILE_C)
```

Comment: I have tried vpath, as follows: `vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES_C)))` but for some reason that didn't seem to make any difference!